# Play Games Services for Web - Increment Event method

Tags: rest, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

Google Play Games services has events mechanism, which has method to increment specific event with amount provided. All the SDKs for Android/iOS/C++, all they have method for incrementing event.

But REST API doesn't have this method (https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/events)

The only one event, which seams to be similar is record event(https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/events/record#auth)

but it requires user to be authenticated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Actually those methods in SDKs also require user to be authenticated, so record method should do the same, I think.